# React PrivateRoute functional component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<RouteProps>): Route<RouteProps>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>): ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps, context?: any): Route<RouteProps>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>) => ReactNode'.  TS2769

    32 | 
    33 |   if (authStatus === AuthStatus.SomeRole) {
  > 34 |     return <Route exact path="/someUrl/" render={<Redirect to="/someUrl" />} />;
       |                                        ^
    35 |   }
```

Interface:

```
interface IPrivateRouteProps {
  component: React.FC;
  path: string;
  exact?: boolean;
}
```

Type

```
type PrivateRouteProps = RouteProps &
  IPrivateRouteProps &
  IAuthenticationState &
  typeof AuthenticationActionCreators.actionCreators;
```

Component:

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const { authStatus } = props;
  ...
  if (authStatus === AuthStatus.SomeRole) {
    return <Route exact path="/someUrl/" render={<Redirect to="/someUrl" />} />;
  }
  ...
};
```

Can you explain to me where this error comes from? If I remove the `render` and replace the `component` in `<Route component={<SomeComponent />} />`, everything works, only the component does not render itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go through react router documentation:

> **render: func**

render requires function. So in your case it should be like this:

```
if (authStatus === AuthStatus.SomeRole) {
    return <Route exact path="/someUrl/" render={(routeProps) => <Redirect to="/someUrl" />} />;
  }
```

If you go little more depth:

**Warning**: `<Route component>` takes precedence over `<Route render>` so don’t use both in the same .

Hope you got the answer. More you can read [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)